# What is American equivalent of "Can you move up a bit"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, american-english, british-english

I the Oxford Dictionary, they say

> **a bit [singular]** (especially British English) a short time or distance
>
> *Can you move up a bit?*

The dictionary didn't say the equivalent expression in American English.

**What is American equivalent of "Can you move up a bit"?**

Comment: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/a%20bit) doesn't list this as a British usage, and even the entry you cite says "especially" not "exclusively", so you'd probably be fine using "a bit". Are you looking for a way of asking someone to move, rather than looking for an alternative to "a bit"?

Comment: What "Oxford Dictionary" are you using?

Comment: It's perfectly understandable in American English too.  I suppose you could also say "move up *a little*."

Answer (score 1):

As the commenters note, this usage is also common in American English. There are plenty of other similar phrases that you could use in various contexts ("move up some," "move up a little," "move up like an inch"), but I see no reason to avoid "move up a bit."